# Is it posible to deactivate an .click(function) while it's proceeding?

Tags: jquery

Another Beginner-Question from myself:

Is it possible to disable an `.click(function)` while it's proceeding [sliding Up/Down and doing some id-switches]?

I have a bunch of anchors using the same function and I don't want users to click on another link while there's still some slidingUp/Down is going on. In order to get this effect i've to block the function while it's proceeding.

Any ideas anyone??

Answer (score 4):

You could check if any of the elements you care about are currently being animated using the [`:animated`](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/) selector, like this:

```
$("a.myClass").click(function() {
  if($("a.myClass:animated").length) return false;
  //animate/do stuff
});
```

While any `a.myClass` elements are being animated, clicks will have no effect.

Comment: @elusive - You can't, re-read the question...*other* elements may be animated, not necessarily the element you're on.  I don't think it's even the same selector actually, probably children/related elements that are being animated.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
$('some_selector').click(function () {
    var running = false;

    return function () {
        if (running === false) {
            running = true;
            // do animation stuff;
            // put this in your callback:
            running = false;
        }

        return false;
    };
}());
```

This disables the animation while `running` equals `true`.

Comment: The scope of `running` wouldn't be consistent across all elements like it needs to be here...also there are simpler ways to do this :)

Comment: @Nick: How is the scope changing? Can you explain that in detail?

Comment: @Nick - It would seem to work with a static number of elements, but not if the handler needs to be bound again to new elements. Is that what you meant? http://jsfiddle.net/jYREj/

Comment: @patrick - correct, it makes this very inflexible and IMO overly complicated when it can be done much simpler :)

Comment: @Nick - Your example is definitely nice and simple. Though here's an example that would seem to work in that situation. http://jsfiddle.net/jYREj/1/ If you return the function to a variable, and use that variable to pass the returned function as the handler, then `running` appears to still be shared.

Comment: @Nick: In this case, there is only one function being bound to all of the elements in `'some_selector'` because the handler is being attached to a single jQuery object. So, the single `running` variable will persist between calls. However, I'd still personally use the `:animated` selector mentioned in other answers

Comment: I personally like the `:animated` method most, too (i simply did not think of it before), but editing my answer to use that method would be kind of thievish, right? ;)

Comment: @Gareth - There's one function being bound *this* time yes, but it precludes you from binding any other elements, it's just inflexible, you're locked into a `running` per-bind.

Comment: @elusive - You may want to clarify that the `running = false` needs to be done in the callback to the animation. :o)

Answer (score 0):

You can set a boolean flag in the click handler and unset it when the animation finishes.

Then, at the top of the handler, you can `return false;` if the flag is set.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`:animated`](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/) selector. As the documentation states, it will return all elements that are currently in progress. If you have specific element that you are checking for, you can use it's ID or class along with this selector to check if it's animation is running.

```
$("#myButton").click(function(){
  if ($("#myDiv:animated").length === 0) {
    // do awesome animation here
  } else {
    // brown explosions! Dumbledore dies, so does Hedwig!
    return false;
  } 
});
```

Comment: Less than zero? How is this ever going to happen? I think you meant `=== 0`.

Comment: Woops. I meant `<=`, but `===` would also work. Anyway, doesn't matter. I think Nick Craver has gone this one in the bag. Merry Christmas!